# Java object access overwriting previous entries

Tags: java, arrays, object

first question attempt here. Trying some interview preparation challenges on parenthesis logging - ie: log the open and close bracket positions of a string. I have tried to use a bracket object, to then use a single array with an open and close position at each entry. The conditions all seem to catch but then the array just duplicates the last results to all entries in the array. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Have left the printing to screen for my attempts to debug this already and know I'm only considering the basic case so far with my algorithm. Thanks in advance.

```
class ParanthesisMatch {

static final char leftBracket = '(';
static final char rightBracket = ')';

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "(I (am (the) basic) case)";
    char[] input = str.toCharArray();

    int opens = 0;
    int closes = 0;
    int brackets = 0;

    Bracket[] bracketArray = new Bracket[10];

    System.out.println(input.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(input[i]);
        if (input[i] == leftBracket) {
            bracketArray[opens] = new Bracket();
            System.out.println("Open trigger: " + i);
            bracketArray[brackets].openBracket = i;
            System.out.println("Open bracket is: " + bracketArray[opens].openBracket);
            brackets++;
            opens++;
        }
        if (input[i] == rightBracket) {
            System.out.println("Close trigger: " + i);
            bracketArray[brackets - closes].closeBracket = i;
            System.out.println("Pos: " + (brackets - closes)
                    + "Close bracket is: " + bracketArray[brackets - closes].closeBracket);
            closes++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < brackets; i++) {
        System.out.println("Bracket: " + i + " Open is " + bracketArray[i].openBracket + ", Close is " + bracketArray[i].closeBracket);
    }
}
}

class Bracket {

public static int openBracket;
public static int closeBracket;

Bracket() {
    openBracket = 0;
    closeBracket = 0;
}

public void setOpen(int open) {
    this.openBracket = open;
}

public void setClose(int close) {
    this.closeBracket = close;
}
}
```

Update - Thank you both very much. I discovered the null pointer exception error after and was able to fix myself with the same change. The static tip was very useful for a lot of issues I've had with my objects! Working code for basic case ( ( ( ) ) ) , not nested ( ( ) ( ) ) yet is:

```
class ParanthesisMatch {

static final char leftBracket = '(';
static final char rightBracket = ')';

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "(I (am (the) basic) case)";
    char[] input = str.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(input.length);

    int opens = 0;
    int closes = 0;
    int brackets = 0;

    Bracket[] bracketArray = new Bracket[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == leftBracket) {
            bracketArray[opens] = new Bracket();
            bracketArray[brackets].setOpen(i);
            brackets++;
            opens++;
        }
        if (input[i] == rightBracket) {
            bracketArray[brackets - 1 - closes].setClose(i);
            closes++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < brackets; i++) {
        System.out.println("Bracket: " + i + " Open is " + bracketArray[i].openBracket + ", Close is " + bracketArray[i].closeBracket);
    }
}
}
class Bracket {
public int openBracket;
public int closeBracket;
Bracket() {
    openBracket = 0;
    closeBracket = 0;
}
public void setOpen(int open) {
    this.openBracket = open;
}
public void setClose(int close) {
    this.closeBracket = close;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

The first problem is in your `Bracket` class:

```
class Bracket {

    public static int openBracket;
    public static int closeBracket;
```

You have declared the fields `openBracket` and `closeBracket` as `static`, which means that they belong to the `Bracket` class itself rather than each `Bracket` object you create.  As a result there is only one copy of each field, shared between the `Bracket` class and all instances of it.  This explains why the same values are shown for each `Bracket` at the end.

However, this is not the only problem.  Take the `static` modifiers away and you get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
        bracketArray[brackets - closes].closeBracket = i;
```

The reason for this is that you are accessing the wrong entry in the array. At the point it fails, `brackets` is 3 and `closes` is 0, but `bracketArray[3]` is still `null`.   You want to be accessing the entry at index 2 instead, so replace `brackets - closes` with `brackets - closes - 1` in all three places you're using it.

After replacing `brackets - closes` with `brackets - closes - 1`, I was able to run your code successfully.

What I found surprising about this was that the NullPointerException appeared after removing the `static` modifier from those two fields.  I made no other modifications, and if I reintroduced the `static` modifier, the NullPointerException went away.  It turns out that even if you have a `null` reference, you can still call `static` methods and access `static` fields.  For example, if you re-introduce the `static` modifier to your fields, then the following line will *not* throw a NullPointerException:

```
    System.out.println(((Bracket) null).openBracket);
```